# having multiple fork and the extra print

Tags: c, unix, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void fork3() 
{
    printf("\n [%d] L0 \n" , getpid() );
    fork();

    printf("\n [%d] L1 \n" , getpid() );
    fork();

    printf("\n [%d] Bye \n", getpid() );
} 

int main ()
{
    fork3();
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
 [2880] L0 

 [2880] L1 

 [2881] L1 

 [2880] Bye 

 [2882] Bye 

 [2881] Bye 

 [2883] Bye
```

The last print is extra! where dose it come from? There is one extra thing I don't understand.Would it be alright if someone explained?

Comment: [if an answer helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) then consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/230282)

Answer (score 2):

After the first call to `fork` two processes are running the program both of which call `fork` creating another two processes. All four processes then call `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Fork splits the program in two (almost) identical pieces (in one (the child) it returns 0 and in the other a >0 pid).

```
      L0
    /    \
   L1     L1
  / \     /  \
 Bye Bye Bye Bye
```

And it's only this simple if your output is a terminal and your messages end with `\n`, because that means each message gets flushed.

With normal block buffering, you'd also get further output duplication due to duplication of the output buffer (which stays empty in your case, due to the `\n`-induced flushes).